# Phone unlocks to settings screen instead of home screen

Tags: google-now, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

Since I updated to android 7.0, my phone will unlock to the settings screen instead of my home screen.

If I lock the phone and then immediately unlock it again, it goes back to the same screen it was on. However, if I let the phone sit for 5 minutes or so it will unlock to the settings panel.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing this and how to fix it? All my research comes up blank. I've looked at the "launch when unlocking" threads, which seems to be a dead end since I have not been messing around with programing. I am using my thumbprint to unlock, not a swipe, so it also does not seem to be related to the "left swipe unlocks to phone, Right to camera, up to home screen."

Version: 7.0

Device: SAMSUNG-SM

Using the google Now launcher

Other update: I am running tasker, but the only thing that is doing is putting my phone on silent when I connect to the work WiFi. I have noticed this happening even when no where near work wifi, but it could still be related.

Comment: Is settings present on the main homescreen?

Comment: Yes, but it is inside a folder of other utility applications. It is not near the bottom of the screen where I could be hitting it by mistake.

Comment: Possible you lcd set is the problem...